# c# return value if match otherwise continue

Tags: c#

This is probably not possible, but the OCD in me wants to at least ask if there is a way :)

I have this method:

```
public async Task<List<Strategy>> Handle(StrategyList query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return _attemptHandler.List();
}
```

I have now added some **Attempts** to help with error handling, so my code changed to this:

```
public async Task<Attempt<List<Strategy>>> Handle(StrategyList query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var attempt = _attemptHandler.List();
    if (attempt.Failed) return attempt.Error;

    return attempt.Result.ToList();
}
```

Think of an `Attempt` like an `IdentityResult`.
What I would like to do, so completely remove the 2nd line so it becomes something like this:

```
public async Task<Attempt<List<Strategy>>> Handle(StrategyList query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var attempt = _attemptHandler.List().ThrowIfError();

    return attempt.Result.ToList();
}
```

So basically, if there was an error trying to get the list, then return that error (in the method `ThrowIfError`) but if there isn't, continue on to the `return attempt.Result.ToList()`.

Is this possible?

You might be asking why. This use case I gave there doesn't look like a lot, but there are some places where I have to check multiple attempts and I would like it if I could do it without having to write the same code over and over (i.e. `if (attempt.Failed) return attempt.Error;`)

---

Here is an example of multiple attempts:

```
public async Task<Attempt<Strategy>> Handle(StrategySave query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var request = query.Model;
    _strategyValidator.Validate(request);

    if (request.Id == 0)
    {
        var attempt = _attemptHandler.Create(request);
        if (attempt.Failed) return attempt.Error;
    }
    else
    {
        var attempt = _attemptHandler.List();
        if (attempt.Failed) return attempt.Error;

        var strategy = attempt.Result.ToList().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id.Equals(query.Model.Id));
        if (strategy == null) return new NotFoundError(nameof(Strategy), query.Model.Id.ToString());

        strategy.Url = request.Url;

        var updateAttempt = _attemptHandler.Update(strategy);
        if (updateAttempt.Failed) return updateAttempt.Error;
    }

    var saveAttempt = await _attemptHandler.SaveChangesAsync();
    if (saveAttempt.Failed) return saveAttempt.Error;

    return request;
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `try catch finally`

Comment: Sure, it's possible. If the `ThrowIfError()` method returns the "attempt" reference passed to it (or `this` if the method is an instance method in the class) and throws an exception if the failed condition holds. This of course requires some changes to the basic error handling. Alternatively, set things up so that your last `ToList()` method can return the value you want. **What have you tried?** _"Is it possible"_ questions are too broad.

Comment: You should check the Result / Option type from functional languages and what .Map() and .Bind() functions do

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You are describing "Rail Oriented Programming", just search for it and you will get some talks, samples with explanations.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the case with multiple attempts? What kind of values you are going to return? Are you returning only one error if first two are attempts were successful but last one failed?

Comment: I have added one of my basic multiple attempts; there are some more that have much more than that, but you should get the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is:

1. a simple implementation of an `Attempt<TResult>` class that lets you do what you want to achieve and
2. a unit test that demonstrates how it is used.

To simplify, the example uses a `List<string>` as the result type. The `HandleAsync` method corresponds to your `Handle` method. `MakeAttemptAsync()` is comparable to your `attemptHandler.List()`.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Utility class that helps shorten the calling code.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Attempt
    {
        public static async Task<Attempt<TResult>> ResultAsync<TResult>(Task<TResult> task)
        {
            return await Attempt<TResult>.ResultAsync(task);
        }

        public static Attempt<TResult> ResultOf<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
        {
            return Attempt<TResult>.ResultOf(func);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a successful or failed attempt.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The result type.</typeparam>
    public class Attempt<TResult>
    {
        private Attempt(TResult result, bool success, Exception exception)
        {
            Result = result;
            Success = success;
            Exception = exception;
        }

        public TResult Result { get; }

        public bool Success { get; }

        public Exception Exception { get; }

        public static async Task<Attempt<TResult>> ResultAsync(Task<TResult> task)
        {
            try
            {
                TResult result = await task;
                return new Attempt<TResult>(result, true, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new Attempt<TResult>(default, false, ex);
            }
        }

        public static Attempt<TResult> ResultOf(Func<TResult> func)
        {
            try
            {
                TResult result = func();
                return new Attempt<TResult>(result, true, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new Attempt<TResult>(default, false, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public class AttemptsTests
    {
        private static readonly List<string> SuccessList = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

        /// <summary>
        /// Simple demonstrator for a short, synchronous handler making use of the
        /// Attempt class, called with flag equal to true or false to simulate
        /// success or failure of the MakeAttemptAsync method.
        /// </summary>
        private static Attempt<List<string>> Handle(bool flag)
        {
            return Attempt.ResultOf(() => MakeAttempt(flag));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Simple demonstrator for a short, asynchronous handler making use of the
        /// Attempt class, called with flag equal to true or false to simulate
        /// success or failure of the MakeAttemptAsync method.
        /// </summary>
        private static async Task<Attempt<List<string>>> HandleAsync(bool flag)
        {
            Task<List<string>> task = MakeAttemptAsync(flag);
            return await Attempt.ResultAsync(task);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Simple dummy method that returns a List or throws an exception.
        /// </summary>
        private static List<string> MakeAttempt(bool flag)
        {
            return flag
                ? SuccessList
                : throw new Exception("Failed attempt");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Simple dummy method that returns a successful or failed task.
        /// </summary>
        private static Task<List<string>> MakeAttemptAsync(bool flag)
        {
            return flag
                ? Task.FromResult(SuccessList)
                : Task.FromException<List<string>>(new Exception("Failed attempt"));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Handle_Failure_ExceptionReturned()
        {
            Attempt<List<string>> attempt = Handle(false);

            Assert.False(attempt.Success);
            Assert.Null(attempt.Result);
            Assert.Equal("Failed attempt", attempt.Exception.Message);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Handle_Success_ListReturned()
        {
            Attempt<List<string>> attempt = Handle(true);

            Assert.True(attempt.Success);
            Assert.Equal(SuccessList, attempt.Result);
            Assert.Null(attempt.Exception);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task HandleAsync_Failure_ExceptionReturned()
        {
            Attempt<List<string>> attempt = await HandleAsync(false);

            Assert.False(attempt.Success);
            Assert.Null(attempt.Result);
            Assert.Equal("Failed attempt", attempt.Exception.Message);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task HandleAsync_Success_ListReturned()
        {
            Attempt<List<string>> attempt = await HandleAsync(true);

            Assert.True(attempt.Success);
            Assert.Equal(SuccessList, attempt.Result);
            Assert.Null(attempt.Exception);
        }
    }
```

#### Update 2020-01-26

I amended the above example by adding a new static `Attempt` utility class that helps shorten the calling code. For example, instead of writing:

```
    return await Attempt<List<string>>.ResultAsync(task);
```

you can write:

```
    return await Attempt.ResultAsync(task);
```

as `TResult` is implicit from the `task` parameter. Secondly, I added a `ResutOf` method that takes a `Func<TResult>`, so you don't need to use `TaskFromResult` to turn a synchronous result into a task.

Comment: This might be me being silly, but your tests show it working when you pass an async method to it. But how would it work if you wanted to test a sync void method?

Comment: Ok, so I got that bit working by doing something similar to this: `var strategies = await Attempt<IQueryable<Strategy>>.ResultAsync(Task.FromResult(_attemptHandler.List()));`

Comment: @r3plica, I assumed the code in your first `Handle` method's body was asynchronous, because of `async Task<Attempt<List<Strategy>>>` in the signature. That's why I only created one example `Result` method that expects a `Task<TResult>`. But it seems your code is actually a good example of why you should use explicit types rather than `var`. Without that, other people can't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for "Rail Oriented Programming", which is exactly what you are trying to achieve.

For example with multiple attempts where next attempt should be executed only when previous one succeed.

```
public Attempt<List<Strategy>> Process(params AttemptHandler[] handlers)
{
    var attempt = default(Attempt<List<Strategy>>);
    foreach(var handler in handlers)
    {
        attempt = handler.List();
        if (attempt.Failed)
        {
            return attempt.Error;
        }
    }

    return attempt.Result.ToList();
}
```

Instead of using `null` as default value for `attempt` variable - use "empty" attempt object, which will return empty attempt if no handlers were provided.

Usage

```
var attempt = Process(_handler1, _handler2, _handler3);
```